# c# Aggregate an enumerable containing a list<string> into one union list then get distinct values

Tags: c#, linq

I am sure the is a elegant way to do this more expressively

```
IEnumerable<List<string>> list = api.call();


            List<string> distinct = new List<string>();
            foreach (var result in list)
            {
                foreach (var subject in result )
                {
                    if (!distinct.Contains(subject))
                    {
                        distinct.Add(subject);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Rahul's answer is perfect, but as a side-note, if you want to make your code more efficient use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>`, then you don't need to use `Contains`. You get the final list with unique strings with `hashSet.ToList()`.

Comment: thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:-

```
List<string> distinct = list.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
```

You can flatten the list using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) and fetch distinct items.

Comment: Logically this is different. You select _all_ items and then call distinct. While he filters _before_ adding.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: the result is the same, but using `Distinct` is much more efficient since it's using a set.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, what do you mean by 'add items'? Where to add? It's iterator.

Comment: @qxg Yes , changed to _select_

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Yeah understood your point but it will result in the expected output plus its efficient right.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't know that. Looking at the [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ab583c7d8e84d6d) it does uses `set`. thanks.